# Terraform - Manipulate local variables

Tags: variables, foreach, terraform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to setup some aws_ssoadmin_managed_policy_attachments (there will end up being a lot) so ideally I just want to be able to update a local variable and then use for_each to go through said variable and churn out a bunch of resources the other side.

I currently have something like the following:

```
locals {
    roles = {
        admin = {
           //managed_policy_name = toset(["AdministratorAccess", "AWSSupportAccess"])
           managed_policy_name = "AWSSupportAccess"
           perm_set_name       = "admin"
        }
       auditor = { ...
    }
}
```

There will be a bunch more roles within this. I use the below to transform it to something more usable by the for_each.

```
managed_policy_map = [for keys, managed_policy_names in local.roles : {
for managed_policy_name in managed_policy_names :
format("%s-%s", keys, managed_policy_name) => { "managed_policy_name" : managed_policy_name }
}]
perm_set_to_managed_policy_map = merge(local.managed_policy_map...)
```

Output from this:

```
a = [{
    "admin-AWSSupportAccess" = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "AWSSupportAccess"
      "perm_set_name" = "admin"
    }
    "admin-admin" = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "admin"
      "perm_set_name" = "admin"
    }
    "auditor-ReadOnlyAccess" = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "ReadOnlyAccess"
      "perm_set_name" = "auditor"
    }
    "auditor-auditor" = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "auditor"
      "perm_set_name" = "auditor"
    }
    "auditor-auditor-permission-set" = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "auditor-permission-set"
      "perm_set_name" = "auditor"
   }
},]
```

Now, ideally, I would like to use the commented managed_policy_name which uses a list (or set to avoid dupes) `//managed_policy_name = toset(["AdministratorAccess", "AWSSupportAccess"])` and cycle through that to end up with something like.

```
a = [{
    "admin-AdministratorAccess" = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "AdministratorAccess"
      "perm_set_name" = "admin"
    }
    "admin-AWSSupportAccess" = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "AWSSupportAccess"
      "perm_set_name" = "admin"
    }
    "auditor-ReadOnlyAccess" = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "ReadOnlyAccess"
      "perm_set_name" = "auditor"
    } ...
```

Is this doable? My assumption is that it will be fairly complicated or I'm missing some Terraform function that makes it easy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your variable structure:

```
locals {
  roles = {
    admin = toset(["AdministratorAccess", "AWSSupportAccess"])
    auditor = ...
  }
}
```

and then simplify your `for` expression:

```
managed_policy_map = [for role, managed_policy_names in local.roles : {
  for policy in managed_policy_names : "${role}-${policy}" => {
    "managed_policy_name" = policy
    "perm_set_name"       = role
  }
}]
```

to easily achieve the same output structure with the `set` type instead of the `string` type:

```
[
  {
    "admin-AWSSupportAccess"    = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "AWSSupportAccess"
      "perm_set_name"       = "admin"
    }
    "admin-AdministratorAccess" = {
      "managed_policy_name" = "AdministratorAccess"
      "perm_set_name"       = "admin"
    }
  },
]
```

I would also recommend simplifying the output structure for easier use in the `for_each` meta-argument according to the intention stated in the question.